# How to cast to an object to a type when type is known during runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a statement something like this: `MyClass myClass = report.DataSource as MyClass`

During runtime, the type of the DataSource is MyClass but it's in a different namespace than the current running project. That's because two projects are creating the same classes from the same service reference. DataSource points to one namespace and the MyClass cast is from a different namesapce. (it's complicated to explain how this occured)

During runtime, how do I use the type returned from report.DataSource.GetType() (returns MyClass from another namespace) and use it as type cast instead of 'MyClass' which is in the namespace which I don't want?

(I hope I've explained it clearly. My brain is foggy now!)

Comment: if you pull your MyClass definition out into a separate assembly shared by your service and clients, the service reference generator will reuse the existing class and make things much easier on you.

Comment: Could you use generics?

Comment: +1 Michael - I was typing that up while you were commenting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to implement my own type converter or using an external tool like automapper for a one time issue was too much work. I opted to copy all the data from one type to the other. I used the javascriptserializer to get just the schema and data without namespaces. Worked beautifully in 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not just that its the "same class in a different namespace"... basically, you have 2 classes. They are completely different classes, because of the auto generated code.

As far as the .Net Runtime is concerned, they might as well be as different as "int" and "string". They probably even hail from different assemblies.

I've had a similar issue as well - and at this point, probably the easiest thing you can do is make your own generic converter method that will read the public properties from the one type, and populate them on the another type.

This can be done because you **PROMISE** that the two classes look identical :)

Comment: Look into [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) if you want something to help perform the conversion, especially if you have a lot of these classes to transfer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two projects that reference the same service (Add Service Reference to the same endpoint). That service returns a DataContract object. You also have one of those projects referencing the other, and using the other project's generated proxy for the service's DataContract.

As others have pointed out, by default the generated proxy types for the DataContract will represent two distinct, incompatible types.

However, if you are able to assume .NET on both the client and the server, you could define the DataContract type in its own assembly that's referenced by all three of the other projects - the service library and the two client projects. It's normally good practice to do this anyway.

Then you can configure the generation of the client proxy (Add Service Reference -> Advanced) to reuse types in the common assembly.

Now there will only be one type for the DataContract that shared by the two client projects.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you want is called "duck typing". You can do this using [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) and find a great example [here](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/05/duck-typing-with-castle-dynamicproxy.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understood clearly your issue, but here it goes

Do not place `using` statements for those classes at the top of your class file - this way you'll always reference them using the full namespace.

Afterwards it's quite easy, as far as i understood

```
MyClass myClass = report.DataSource as MyClass
if(myClass==null)
  //do the second conversion
```

If the namespace fully (or partially) collides use one of the two

1. `global::` keyword when referencing the class
2. `extern alias` in one or both your assemblies that have MyClass

If you want to convert one class to the other implement your custom converter.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be suitable for your purpose, but to be complete, I mention the compile-time option available to you: Interfaces.

If you make an interface in an assembly that *CAN* be shared at compile time, you can cast to that interface at any time.